# How to merge arrays of react-router-config correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-config

I would like to use it to build my route configuration, but my route configuration will come from multiples packages within `node_modules` and require to be merged correctly prior usage.

### Route Configuration Shape

Routes are objects with the same properties as a `<Route>` with a couple differences:

- the only `render` prop it accepts is `component` (no `render` or `children`)
  introduces the routes key for sub routes
- Consumers are free to add any additional props they'd like to a route, you can access `props.route` inside the component, this object is a reference to the object used to render and match.
- accepts `key` prop to prevent remounting component when transition was made from route with the same component and same `key` prop

```
const routes = [
  { component: Root,
    routes: [
      { path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: Home
      },
      { path: '/child/:id',
        component: Child,
        routes: [
          { path: '/child/:id/grand-child',
            component: GrandChild
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So if I have this second route config to be merged :

```js
const routes = [
  { component: Root,
    name: 'root',
    routes: [
      { path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: Home
      },
      { path: '/child/:id',
        name: 'childView',
        routes: [
          { path: '/child/:id/related-child',
            component: RelatedChild
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to have one correspondance with all the key for every nested route, a merge.

How can I do that

How can I do that?